# Searching Files according to PNG Meta-Tags

Tags: files, file-metadata, png

I want to search for PNG's in a (sub-)folder structure with the meta tag `software` set to the value `GNOME::ThumbnailFactory` and delete them with a single bash command.


Have the story behind it, you can skip that if you want:
I scrapped my Ubuntu ext filesystem by formatting the drive, and then decided to save my files with `PhotoRec`. My problem now is that now I have all my files wildly distributed in some sub-folders, and guess it, the hidden Gnome Thumbnail folder is also evenly distributed in it and way larger than the original files because it also indexed my external harddrive I had mounted on it sometimes. I found out all of them had the PNG Software Tag set to the `GNOME::ThumbnailFactory` value by looking at some of them with `ExifToolGUI` in Windows, but I'm not able to find out how I can do that and delete them according to the results with a Linux Command Line Tool, and I'm not very proficient with `grep` to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using ImageMagick. Once ImageMagick is installed, use command `identify -verbose image.jpg` and pick what you want from the output using `grep`

```
find / -name "*.png" -exec sh -c '
  if identify -verbose "${file}" | grep your_pattern_here
  then
    echo "${file}" # or do something else here, e.g. rm
  fi
' {} \;
```

Comment: Doesn't that only put the result for one image? I want to search them according to said tag

Comment: Yeah... that is what a `for` loop for. You can loop through files one by one, as it should be done. See my updates in the answer above